# Do I need a sleep time in my worker role?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-worker-roles

I have a worker role monitoring a queue.  As much as I would like it to be slammed, most of the time that queue will be empty.  I get a new item in the queue every couple of minutes.

I have:

```
 public override void Run()
 {
     while (true)
     {
         //Check the queue for new messages
         //if there's a new message, do some stuff
     }
 }
```

My question is, do I need to do a Thread.Sleep(x) if there isn't an item in the queue?  Or can I just keep checking it over and over?  If I do need to sleep, how long should I sleep for?  (milliseconds/seconds?)

My main concern is Azure charges.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good approach to help minimize transaction charges (which is I think your primary concern) would be to go with a backoff polling approach.  Meaning, slowly increase the sleep time each time there isn't a queue message to be found.  Doing so until the sleep time reaches some maximum value.  Once a message is found, then start to poll faster for messages.

Another way to help would be to grab multiple messages from the queue at once (instead of getting one at a time).  That will help with the transaction charges as well.

Comment: Mike's comments are perfect.  With respect to the actual time values, I would suggest checking into Storage pricing, you pay $0.01 for every 10k transactions.  The actual frequency of checking should be a balance between how many transactions you're willing to pay for vs. how quickly do you want your workers to start processing the workload.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I think I'm going to just have it wait 1 second if there isn't an item in the queue.  With that, at worst I'll pay 87 cents a day.  It takes about 2 seconds to process an item and I'm getting about 500 items a day, so it should be a little less than that.

My users expect their files to be processed quickly after upload, so this works out really well.

Comment: Think you may have got it wrong by a factor of 10 : 0.01 / 10,000 * 60 * 60 * 24 = 0.087 or 8.7c per day.

Comment: Did i misunderstood something - but was transactions within the datacenter not free? So if the worker role run within the same datacenter its fine?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at:
http://windowsazurecat.com/2010/12/best-practices-for-maximizing-scalability-and-cost-effectiveness-of-queue-based-messaging-solutions-on-windows-azure/

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend that you check the DequeueCount on the message to avoid unnecessary processing / charges on poisoned messages.
For example logging and deleting messages that exceeed a set dequeue count rahter than spinning on whatever sleepperiod you hav ein your message loop.

Comment: Thanks, that's a big one. I was running a local test last night and found a poison message and my computer tried to process it all night long.  This strategy will help get around that.